# Not able execute ansible play book using jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

Getting below error in Jenkins console output,

```
[Pipeline] ansiblePlaybook [pipeline -job] $ ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml -i inventories/a/hosts FATAL: command execution failed java.io.IOException: Process working directory '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/pipeline -job' doesn't exist! at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:248) at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.(Proc.java:219) at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:937) at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:455)
```

My Jenkins pipeline is

```
pipeline { 
  agent any 
  stages { 
    stage('Build') { 
      steps { 
         ansiblePlaybook( credentialsId: 'private_key', inventory: 'inventories/a/hosts', playbook: 'my_playbook.yml') 
            }
          }
        }
       }
```

Comment: By any chance your job is called `pipeline -job` (with a space)?

Comment: As guessed by @MaratC this is probably due to you job name containing a space. Meanwhile, which version of Jenkins are your running ? Because i cannot reproduce this in 2.190.2: the pipeline succeed even if the job name contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add installation: "ansible", in my command, where "ansible" is the name of the Ansible installation in Jenkins Global Tool Configuration (where the "Path to ansible executables directory" has to be provided).

Also the ansible playbook has to be in the workspace folder. See this post to copy to workspace folder [how to copy files from a directory outside the workspace to workspace in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961806/how-to-copy-files-from-a-directory-outside-the-workspace-to-workspace-in-jenkins) (This needs file-operations jenkins plugin to work. https://plugins.jenkins.io/file-operations/)

```
            ansiblePlaybook (
                playbook: "first.ansible",
                colorized: true,
                installation: "ansible"
            )
```